# Creating custom tooltip for Google Combo Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, tooltip

For my question I have prepared a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/whznhvsj/):

[image: chart screenshot]

In a Combo Chart with stepped area and a dashed line I am trying to display [a tooltip with custom text](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content), because the default text ("652 Win: 85" in the above screenshot) is difficult to understand.

My JavaScript code is below (the data is actually coming from a PHP-script + database but for simplicity I have just put it into the `jsonData` variable):

```
  google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawComboChart);

  function drawComboChart() {
      var jsonData = {
          "cols": [{
                  "label": "Game",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Win",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Defeat",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Draw",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Opponent score",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "role": "tooltip",
                  "type": "string"
              }
          ],
          "rows": [{
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 646
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 646 0:10 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 647
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 13
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 647 0:13 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 648
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 22
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 23
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 648 22:23 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 651
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 13
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 31
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 651 13:31 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 652
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 85
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 75
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 652 85:75 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 653
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 653 0:10 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 654
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 18
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 12
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 654 18:12 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 655
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 22
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 655 10:22 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 661
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 33
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 44
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 661 33:44 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 666
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 5
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 18
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 666 5:18 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 682
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 95
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 107
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 682 95:107 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 686
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 686 0:10 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 733
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 389
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 387
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 733 389:387 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 737
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 29
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 12
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 737 29:12 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 979
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 152
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 70
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 979 152:70 won"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      };
      var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
      //dt.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
      var options = {
          width: 480,
          height: 360,
          legend: {
              position: 'top',
              alignment: 'center',
              maxLines: 2
          },
          seriesType: 'steppedArea',
          series: {
              3: {
                  type: 'line',
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  color: '000000',
                  lineDashStyle: [4, 2]
              }
          }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dt, options);
  }
```

As you see in the above code, I have added a column:

```
  {
      "role": "tooltip",
      "type": "string"
  }
```

And try to fill it with following values:

```
  {
      "v": "Game 737 29:12 won"
  }
```

But still, when hovering over stepped area, the default tooltip is shown.

Only when hovering over the dashed line is the new custom tooltip to see.

How to enable the custom tooltip everywhere please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tooltip column role will only represent the data column it follows...

to *enable the custom tooltip everywhere*,
you'll need to add a tooltip column after every data column...

see following working snippet...

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawComboChart);

  function drawComboChart() {
      var jsonData = {
          "cols": [{
                  "label": "Game",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Win",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "role": "tooltip",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Defeat",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "role": "tooltip",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Draw",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "role": "tooltip",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              {
                  "label": "Opponent score",
                  "type": "number"
              },
              {
                  "role": "tooltip",
                  "type": "string"
              }
          ],
          "rows": [{
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 646
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 646 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 646 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 646 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 646 0:10 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 647
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 647 0:13 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 647 0:13 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 647 0:13 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 13
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 647 0:13 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 648
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 22
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 648 22:23 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 648 22:23 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 648 22:23 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 23
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 648 22:23 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 651
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 13
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 651 13:31 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 651 13:31 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 651 13:31 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 31
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 651 13:31 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 652
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 85
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 652 85:75 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 652 85:75 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 652 85:75 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 75
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 652 85:75 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 653
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 653 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 653 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 653 0:10 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 653 0:10 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 654
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 18
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 654 18:12 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 654 18:12 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 654 18:12 won"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 12
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 654 18:12 won"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "c": [{
                          "v": 655
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 655 10:22 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 10
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 655 10:22 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 0
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 655 10:22 lost"
                      },
                      {
                          "v": 22
                      },
                      {
                          "v": "Game 655 10:22 lost"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      };
      var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
      //dt.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
      var options = {
          width: 480,
          height: 360,
          legend: {
              position: 'top',
              alignment: 'center',
              maxLines: 2
          },
          seriesType: 'steppedArea',
          series: {
              3: {
                  type: 'line',
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  color: '000000',
                  lineDashStyle: [4, 2]
              }
          }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dt, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks... Since there can only be either a "Win", a "Defeat" or a "Draw", I could print an empty tooltip (i.e. `{ v: "" }` after other ones, to save some data